# Application helpers overriding engine helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I have mounted an engine that in turn uses the devise gem.  The engine's controllers use the devise helper `sign_in`.  My application does not use devise for authentication, but it does have its own `sign_in` helper.  When the engines session controller is accessed from context of the application, the applications `sign_in` overrides the engines/devise `sign_in` helper.  How do I stop this overriding?

Comment: It may help you, specify helpers in engine.rb as below. which allow you to access engine helpers
ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
  helper Engine::NameHelper
end

Comment: I am not sure how to use this as the helper is not in one of the engine's helper classes but is a device helper, i.e. and engine within an engine.